# Can TidHttpServer (Delphi XE2) handle urlencoded characters?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I have a TidHttpServer listening to port 8844 with the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document <> '/favicon.ico' then
  begin
    Memo1.Text := ARequestInfo.Params.Text;
  end;
end;
```

This is compiled with Delphi XE2. When I browse to

```
http://localhost:8844/document?Value=%F6   <-- %F6 is the encoded value for ö
```

...I get the result:

```
value=?
```

If i compile the application using Delphi 2007 I get the following result

```
value=ö
```

Is this a bug in Indy of something that I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XE2, strings are Unicode.  When `TIdHTTPServer` decodes the `ARequestInfo.Document` in D2009 and later, it requires percent-encoded data to decode into UTF-8 encoded data, which is then decoded into the final Unicode string.  There is currently no option to change that (I have submitted a feature request to our issue trackers for it).  `%F6` does not represent a valid UTF-8 octet, which is why you end up with `'?'`.  In UTF-8, the `'ö'` character would be UTF-8 encoded as `$C3 $B6` and thus percent-encoded as `%C3%B6`, not `%F6`.

In D2007, strings are Ansi.  When `TIdHTTPServer` decodes the `ARequestInfo.Document` in D2007 and earlier, it provides the decoded data as-is, thus `%F6` would decode into `$F6` and be stored as `#246`.  That value is then interpretted by the RTL using whatever the local machine's default Ansi codepage is, so it would represent the `'ö'` character only for Ansi codepages that define it that way (Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 do, but ISO-8859-5 does not, for example).

I would suggest you change your server logic to use UTF-8 encoded URLs in both Delphi versions.  In D2007, you can use the RTL's `UTF8Decode()` function to decode a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` into a `WideString`, which you can then assign to another `AnsiString` to convert the data into the Ansi value you were originally expecting.  In D009+, that is handled automatically for you.

On a side note, accessing a UI component directly in the `OnCommandGet` event is not thread-safe.  ou have to synchronize with the main thread in order to access the UI safely.